# Join columns from two tables to just one entity in the TypeORM

Tags: typescript, database, relational-database, typeorm

I'm in a project for which there is already a defined database, and I need to transform this data into entities in the application layer.

#### There are these tables:

[image]

These two tables technically represent just one entity, and I wouldn't want to subclass the normal TypeORM link to these joins.

#### I would like to have something like this:

Obs: Have entity attributes referring to columns from another table

```js
@Entity({name: "MAIN_order"})
export class Order {

  @Column({name: "number"})
  public num: number;

  @Column({name: "res_code"})
  public resCode: string;

  /*
  Many-to-many for order users (ignore)

  public users: User[];
  */

  @Column()
  public open: boolean;

  @Column({name: "date_start"})
  public dateStart: Date;

  @Column({name: "date_end"})
  public dateEnd: Date;

  @Column()
  public obs: string;

  @Column()
  public origin: boolean;

  /* ======== ANOTHES TABLE (MAIN_corre_order) ======== */

  /*
  one-to-many for order issues (ignore)

  public issues: string[];
  */

  @Column()
  public detail: string;

  @Column()
  public cause: string;

  @Column()
  public action: string;

  @Column({name: "type_code"})
  public type: string;
}
```

Is there a way to do this in TypeORM? How ?